# Textbox Methods

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, textbox

I'm not sure if this title is accurate so if not please let me know and I'll edit it. So I have two methods, one to load messages from a csv file and iterate through them on a button click which will print the next values to the corresponding textboxes:

```
   int index = 0;



    void LoadMessages()
    {

        var messageType = new List<string>();
        var messageSender = new List<string>();
        var messageContent = new List<string>();

        using (var rd = new StreamReader("messages.csv"))
        {
            while (!rd.EndOfStream)
            {
                var splits = rd.ReadLine().Split(',');
                messageType.Add(splits[0]);
                messageSender.Add(splits[1]);
                messageContent.Add(splits[2]);
            }
        }


        txtMessageType.Text = messageType[index];
        txtSender.Text = messageSender[index];
        txtContent.Text = messageContent[index];
        index++;
        if (index == messageType.Count)
            index = 0;
    }
```

And another which will replace any text from the txt.content.Text which is in a url format:

```
    void RemoveURLs()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"http(s)?://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=])?");
        txtContent.Text = regex.Replace(txtContent.Text, "<URL Quarrantined>");
    }
```

However when I run the application LoadMessages works fine and messages are printed to the textboxes but when I click the button I'm using to replace the urls nothing happens.

If I comment out the txtContent.Text in the load messages like below and run the code, the URLs will now be replaced:

```
        //txtContent.Text = messageContent[index];
```

Would anyone be able to explain what's going on and how I would remedy this, I've been online and on SA searching for solutions but I'm not exactly sure what I'm even looking for? Thanks for any help you can offer!

Edit: I've added the button code and XAML.

```
    private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadMessages();
    }

    private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RemoveURLs();

         var dictionary = File.ReadAllLines(@"textwords.csv")
          .Select(x => x.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
          .ToDictionary(key => key.FirstOrDefault().Trim(),
           value => value.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Trim());

         if (txtMessageType.Text.StartsWith("S"))
         {
             aMessage.MessageType = "SMS Message";
         }
         else if (txtMessageType.Text.StartsWith("E"))
         {
             aMessage.MessageType = "Email";
         }
         else if (txtMessageType.Text.StartsWith("T"))
         {
             aMessage.MessageType = "Tweet";
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("Invalid Message Format");
         }
        
     }
```

XAML

```
<Border Padding="10">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <!-- Button Area -->
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button x:Name="btnLoad" Margin="0,0,10,0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Load Next Message" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnLoad_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="btnFilter" Grid.Column="1" Content="Filter Message" Click="btnFilter_Click" />
            <Button x:Name="btnExport" Margin="10 0 0 0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Export Message" Click="btnExport_Click" />

        </Grid>
        <!-- Message Area -->
        <TextBlock Text="Message Type" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 10 0 0" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtMessageType" Padding="2"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Sender" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 10 0 0" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtSender" Padding="2"/>

        <TextBlock Text="Message Content" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0 10 0 0" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtContent" Padding="2" Height="200"/>

    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger or try/catch to see what error is being thrown? Do some logging and find out what the actual error ... which would be most useful.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors thrown which is why I'm confused

Comment: Can you add the code which the button executes and a small xaml snippet of the controls in question?

Comment: Hi sorry, I'll add the following about

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that it works as expected. The only reason I can think of, where it's not working as expected, is if the regex isn't catching your URL.

For example

if Message content is like this: "mess1 https://www.microsoft.com/ messend" it will be replaced with this string: "mess1 <URL Quarrantined> messend". I guess this is what you expect.

But if Message content is like this: "mess1 htps://www.microsoft.com/ messend" it will not be replaced. ("htps" is missing a "t"). The Message content will contain the same text as before.

To check your regex, you can add this line to the RemoveURLs function and see if "match.Success" is true (found) or false (not found).

```
        Match match = regex.Match(txtContent.Text);
```